# Looking for a css selector that selects all childs after nth child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any css selector available that selects all childs AFTER a specific child?

For instance, I have a parent that has 10 child elements. I want to hide all child elements coming after the 4th child.

Is there any selector that lets me select all childs after the 4th one?

I know I can do the reverse i.e. : Hide all and only show the first 4 ones but I was wondering if the reverse is possible.

My current sollution:

```
.parent .child {
    display: none;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(-n+4){
    display: block;
}
```

My desired sollution:

```
.parent .child {
    display: block;
}
.parent .child*some selector that selects all after the 4th child*{
    display: none;
}
```

My expected outcome:

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/b0Lrehpu/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.parent .child:nth-child(n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: How the hell did I miss that -.- thnx

Answer (score 2):

This would also work:

```
.parent .child {
    display: block;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(4) ~ .child{
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b0Lrehpu/3/

Answer (score 1):

Well...

Maybe you're looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/vw8cjwa8/

**CSS**

```
.parent .child {
    display: block;
}
.parent .child:nth-child(n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The point with the `red` was to show him that it was working and that he could do anything he'd like to :). Anyway, you're in the right though so I edited my post ;).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sibling selector `~` in order to achieve this in combination to an nth-child selector.

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (~) character
>   that separates two sequences of simple selectors. ~ [w3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general)

A quick demo would be:

```css
.parent div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.parent div:nth-child(4) {
  background: lime;
}
.parent div:nth-child(4) ~ div {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

- [more information on nth-child](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child)
- [more information on ~ selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general)